# SQL query to map duplicated entries for data enrichment

Tags: sql, postgresql, deduplication

I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL.

I'm planning on running a data set of products through mechanical turk to enrich the data with pricing information.  The problem is that I have 80,000 records uploaded by users, many of which are in actuality duplicates, although they may have other parameters not duplicate.

If I enrich data from a SELECT DISTINCT query, the problem is I won't have a way to add that data to the actual "duplicate" entries.

How can I see all the rows eliminated from a SELECT DISTINCT query, such that I can go back and enrich those rows with my new data later?

Comment: `that I have 80,000 records uploaded by users, many of which are in actuality duplicates, although they may have other parameters not duplicate.` Please learn about data modelling. What you have stored in one table should probably be normalised into two, three or more tables.

Comment: @wildplasser I suspect it's dirty data that's being cleaned up and normalised, but requires hand cleanup.

Comment: Yes indeed, dirty data that's getting cleaned up.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `DISTINCT`, you should `GROUP BY` the fields you want to treat as indicating a duplicate.

Then you have a few options:

- `array_agg` the non-grouped-by rows;
- Put a `GROUP BY ... HAVING count(...) > 1` query in a subquery you use in the `FROM` clause, then self-join on the original table on the same columns as you grouped by. That'll let you find all rows that have duplicates.
- Use a window function to `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as dup_num` where `col1, col2, col3` are the cols you currently have in the `DISTINCT` query. Then wrap that up as a subquery-in-FROM and filter for `WHERE dup_num > 1`. This approach lets you find only the *duplicate* rows, i.e. it excludes one row that it treats as the original row. To control which gets treated as duplicate and which as original you can use an `ORDER BY` clause inside the `OVER (...)` window.

I'm pretty sure there are lots of examples already on how to find and return duplicates. I suggest searching Stack Overflow under the [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) tag for queries to find duplicates.

Comment: Using array_agg proved to be effective.  Now I have a map between the unique instances of each product, and all it's duplicates.